# Getting average of a numerical field across multiple nodes

Tags: views

I have a node type with a decimal field on it that saves percentages from 0-100%.

I want to get the average percentage from across all the nodes in that node type. So that no matter how many nodes are created under that node type, I can show the average on a landing page elsewhere using views.

Using drupal 8 and struggling to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Open your view in edit mode.
2. Open the **Advanced** tab.
3. Find the section named **Other**
4. Enable the **Use aggregation** option
5. Click on the **Aggregation settings** option for your desired field
6. Select **Average** from **Aggregation type** select list

[image: enable aggregation]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have followed this and I just end up seeing the field result for each node of the content type im filtering for. This hasn't done anything, how can it show just one result which is the average of all of them?

The fields I have showing are Title and Score (this is the one im using to average which is an decimal field).